# How to run Higher version application in lower version?

Tags: android

I have developed one application which is running properly in android 4.0(icecream Sandwhich) but not working in 2.3.3(ginger Bread).

It is showing the error like process example.app_name is stopped unexpectedly in 2.3.3 but its 
working fine in 4.0.3.

Is any one know that app has to be run on version 2.3.3 ?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You need to debug it. Hook it up to your USB and find the error logs, and go from there. If all you're getting is error logs through the developer console, you need to look at those, too. My guess is it's some `NoSuchMethodException` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it may work

add this line to your code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

add this as child of `<manifest>` tag and change values according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

The Support Package includes static "support libraries" that you can add to your Android application in order to use APIs that are either not available for older platform versions or that offer "utility" APIs that aren't a part of the framework APIs. The goal is to simplify your development by offering more APIs that you can bundle with your application so you can worry less about platform versions.

Go thrue the step **Setting Up a Project to Use a Library**

And also set the **min. SDK version in Manifest**, otherwise you won't be able to install your application to device